# Страхующий код для getattr()

Tags: python

Ревьюрер просит написать страхующий код для getattr(), но я не понимаю как это реализовать.
Использовать лучше ValueError или TypeError? AttributeError использовать не рекомендует.
И как правильно это вставить в код?

Кратко цель задачи:

В первой строке записано количество команд n — целое число, не превосходящее 5000.
Во второй строке записано число m — максимальный размер дека. Он не превосходит 1000.

В следующих n строках записана одна из команд:

- push_back(value) – добавить элемент в конец дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
- push_front(value) – добавить элемент в начало дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
- pop_front() – вывести первый элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».
- pop_back() – вывести последний элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».

На ввод подается:

```
4
4
push_front 861
push_front -819
pop_back
pop_back
```

То правильный ответ:

```
861
-819
```

Мой код:

````
class Deque:
    def __init__(self, max_size: int):
        self._elements = [None] * max_size
        self._max_size = max_size
        self._head = - 1
        self._tail = 0
        self._size = 0

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0

    def push_back(self, value: int):
        if self._size == self._max_size:
            raise OverflowError
        self._elements[self._tail] = value
        self._tail = (self._tail + 1) % self._max_size
        self._size += 1

    def push_front(self, value: int):
        if self._size == self._max_size:
            raise OverflowError
        self._elements[self._head] = value
        self._head = (self._head - 1) % self._max_size
        self._size += 1

    def pop_back(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError
        self._tail = (self._tail - 1) % self._max_size
        self._size -= 1
        return self._elements[self._tail]

    def pop_front(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError
        self._head = (self._head + 1) % self._max_size
        self._size -= 1
        return self._elements[self._head]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_command = int(input())
    queue = Deque(int(input()))
    for _ in range(count_command):
        operation, *parameters = input().split()
        method = getattr(queue, operation) # здесь вызов 
        try:
            result = method(*parameters)
        except (IndexError, OverflowError):
            result = 'error'
        if result is not None:
            print(result)```
````

Comment: А почему бы у него и не спросить?

Answer (score 1):

У `getattr` есть параметр `default`, куда можно поставить значение которое будет возвращаться, если атрибут не найден в объекте. Тогда можно выполнить простую проверку не вызывая/обрабатывая исключения.

Пример:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def push(self, val: int):
        self.x += val

test_class = SomeClass()

m = 'push'
method = getattr(test_class, m, None)
if method:
    method(5)
    print(test_class.x) # 5
m = 'poll'
method = getattr(test_class, m, None)
if not method:
    print(f'method {m} not found')
```

В вашем случае, по мимо этого, можно добавить проверку на наличие параметров `*parameters` если они необходимы, но это уже выходит за рамки вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

зачем? у getattr 3 параметра. если третий указать то ты не получишь AttributeError. Укажи туда lambda например, чтобы выполнение зашло в try и там уже либо выкинь исключение которое уже ловишь или действие по умолчанию. не знаю. сам реши.

```
class Foo: ...


f = Foo()
attr = getattr(f, "unknown", lambda: f)
print(attr())
```

А логика наверное такая. У тебя operation это пользовательский ввод. А пользователю свойственно ошибаться. Все что тебя просят это не выкидывать некрасивую ошибку AttributeError и стектрейс к ней, а указать, что данной операции нет продолжение невозможно. Ну это я так понял. Как на самом деле я хз

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_command = int(input())
    queue = Deque(int(input()))
    for _ in range(count_command):
        operation, *parameters = input().split()
        method = getattr(queue, operation, lambda *a, **k: "Операция не найдена...") # здесь вызов 
        try:
            result = method(*parameters)
        except (IndexError, OverflowError):
            result = 'error'
        if result is not None:
            print(result)
```

Типо такого